# How to pass from a double-supply filter circuit to a single supply filter circuit?

Tags: low-pass, single-supply-op-amp, sallen-key

So here is the main circuit, it's a lowpass filter-4th order bessel, so 2 sallen-key low-pass circuits in cascade. I already have all the components and transfer functions figured out but i would like to have a single supply instead of 2 supplies.

[image: 2 sallen-key low-pass circuits in cascade]

The bode plot of this circuit below.

[image]

I found a cook book recipe for a single supply circuit, i tried changing the values of R5 and R6 with a sine wave as a test function and it works here, the output is centered at 2.5 .

[image]

So now i tried doing the same to only 1 sallen key circuit (ignore the floating voltage sources)

[image]
All i get is gibberish, i dont know why this happens and how to fix this and i would like to get some advice if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the AC coupling capacitor C15 which you've set to 0.5uF. You should increase this capacitor and resistors R17 and R18. because it acts as a high-pass filter with a corner frequency of W=1/(2*pi(RC)), so there's a gain drop in low frequencies.

Comment: So with the capacitor at 10uF and both resistors at 100k the bode plots results are what it should be, thanks. I would like to point out that at 100k it's a bigger value than the resistors used in the actual filters, can that be a problem? I mean there's nothing wrong in the bode plots but i am not sure. Also is there any other way to find the actual values for the capacitor and resistances without guessing?

Comment: @G0tBlackOps No problem. With 100K there would be no problem because usually the bias current of inputs of a OPAMP is in order of nA or uA.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this as your input circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTB8JE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It shifts an input signal by half of the supply voltage, and does so without an AC coupling capacitor (which attenuates low frequencies and blocks DC).

[You may *want* to attenuate low frequencies and block DC. If so, then a coupling capacitor may be your best choice.]

[image]

If your input has higher frequency components that you wish to attenuate at this stage, you may add a capacitor in parallel with R3.

The input impedance is 150 k\$\Omega\$. If this is too low, you could multiply every resistor by some constant. Depending upon your op-amp, you may not want to go *too* high.